# Blackberry 4.6 OS how to get thumbnails for the image files

Tags: blackberry, thumbnails

I hav to show all the image files  in device along with their thumbnails.
for 4.6 os devices i am unable to get thumbnails.

to create thumbnail i have first read the bitmap from file then I have scaled it.

I am getting error File system out of resources while reading image file.

Thanks
Sudha

Comment: Could you post the code and the full exception message, as well as the line where it happens?